# vim ftplugin cant link executable

Tags: vim, compilation, linker, fortran

I am writing a `vim` `ftplugin` for `fortran`:

```
"global values
let s:Compiler  =   'gfortran'
let s:ObjExt    =   '.o'
let s:ModExt    =   '.mod'
let s:ExeExt    =   '.run'
let s:VimComp   =   'gfortran'
let s:FCFlags   =   '-Wall -g -O0 -c'
let s:FLFlags   =   '-Wall -g -O0'
let s:OutputGvim=   'vim'

" Compile: compile the current file
function! Compile()

  exe ":cclose"
  exe ":update"

  let sou = expand("%:p")
  let obj = expand("%:p:r").s:ObjExt

  if !filereadable(obj) || (filereadable(obj) && (getftime(obj)<getftime(sou)))
    let makeprg_saved = '"'.&makeprg.'"'
    exe "setlocal makeprg=".s:Compiler
    let v:statusmsg = ''
    exe "make ".s:FCFlags. " " .sou. " -o " .obj
    if empty(v:statusmsg)
      :let &statusline = "'".obj."':Compiled successfully"
    endif
    if v:shell_error !=0
      :let &statusline = v:shell_error
    endif
    :redraw!
    exe ":botright copen"
  else
    :let &statusline = "'".obj."':is up to date"
  endif
endfunction

" Link: Compile and link 
function! Link()
  "compile first
  call Compile()
  let sou = expand("%:p")
  let obj = expand("%:p:r").s:ObjExt
  let exe = expand("%:p:r").s:ExeExt

  if filereadable(exe)                      &&
        \ filereadable(obj)                 &&
        \ filereadable(sou)                 &&
        \ (getftime(exe) >= getftime(obj))  &&
        \ (getftime(obj) >= getftime(sou))
    :let &statusline = " '".exe."' is up to date "
    return
  endif

  let v:statusmsg = ""
    let makeprg_saved = '"'.&makeprg.'"'
    exe "setlocal makeprg=".s:Compiler
 "#######################################
 "Expect to create the executable here
  silent exe "make " .s:FLFlags." ".obj. " -o " .exe
 "#######################################
  if empty(v:statusmsg)
    :let &statusline="'".exe."': Successfully Linked"
    redraw!
    exe ":botright cwindow"
  else
    exe ":botright copen"
  endif
endfunction
```

The first function (`Compile`) creates the object file and the second function (`Link`) calls the `Compile` first and then links the file to create the executable.

The problem is, for a fresh code, say, `hello.f90`, without any object files yet created, I run `Link()`, with the hope that, Link will call `Compile` first (which it is doing) and the link the executable as in the line

```
silent exe "make " .s:FLFlags." ".obj. " -o " .exe
```

But it is not creating that. For a fresh run, only `.o` file is created. If I rerun Link() (Now, `.o` already exists), then the executable is created.

But I don't see a reason why executable is not created in the first run.

Kindly help.

NB. for vimmers not familiar with fortran, a simple hello.f90 is:

```
!File=hello.f90
Program hello
  Implicit None
  write(*,*) "Hello World"
End Program hello
```

`gfortran` is the `gnu fortran compiler`